# How to use chrono to determine runtime

Tags: c++, list, vector, compiler-optimization, c++-chrono

I want to determine which is a better container to use for certain operations, therefore I have to check the run time of a vector vs a list.

The references online have been quite vague or too complex for this implementation.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean "How do I measure the time in execution" or "how do I measure the time it takes to compile"? Typically, I use a command like `time myprog` or `time g++ {options} myprog.cpp` to measure time - but that assumes it's a reasonably long runtime - at least a second or two.

Comment: I don't think it's the *compile* time you're interested in, but the *run* time? And in general, you take a snapshot of the time before you're doing the operation, and another when the operation is done, then you just check the difference between the two times.

Comment: How would I get the respective start and end times?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have access to a `C++11` compiler,

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
    // code you want to time here
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _end(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
                    _end - _start).count(); // in seconds, read more about std::chrono
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but receiving a ton of errors. I have the <chrono> header file but it keeps telling me: 'std::chrono' has not been declared|

Comment: compile with `-std=c++11`, <chrono> is part of C++11 standard

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've use it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ... code to measure here ... 
    auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff);
    std::cout << "Loop1: " << t1.count() << std::endl;
```

You will need to compile that with `g++ -std=c++11`, and as long as you have a working C++11 compiler and library, that should work.

Comment: I'd use `steady_clock` instead, the `high_resolution_clock` may change if one changes the system time during runtime, although probably this never happens...

Comment: Not something I (or my system) does very often... I expect high res clock does, at least on some systems, give a higher resolution, and at least in some cases, that's more important. But I admit I just copied this from some code I had, without much thought as to what different clock sources there may be, and their advantage/disadvantages.

Comment: Yes, I also used before high_resolution_clock, but had an issue when I had to time a simulation that took like 2 days, and some guy just changed the wall time. And it seems that, as you said, (although not guaranteed by the standard), both have the same precision.

Comment: I've only ever used this for things that take a few seconds or minutes. For things that take a while, I've typically just used standard `time` (which also has the same problem that you describe, of course). Or the `time` commandline tool on Linux - saves having to change the code...

Comment: granted, I guess you use steady_clock if you're really paranoid that something may happen during runtime :D

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <typename Container>
void fill_container(Container& c, int n)
{
int v;

for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
{
    v= rand() %12;
    c.push_back(v);
}

}

template<typename Container>
void print(Container& c, ostream& out =cout)
{
typename Container::iterator itr = c.begin();
cout << "now" ;
while(itr!=c.end())
{
    out << *itr << endl;
    itr++;
}

}

template <typename Container>
void removeOdd(Container& c)
{
 typename Container::iterator itr2 = c.begin();
 while(itr2!= c.end())
 {
        cout << *itr2 << endl;
         if(*itr2 %2 != 0 )
        {
            itr2 = c.erase(itr2);
        }
        itr2++;
 }

 }

int main()
{





//Timer ends
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
// code you want to time here
vector<int> damn;
fill_container(damn, 20);
removeOdd(damn);
print(damn);
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _end(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());

std:: cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>( _end - _start).count();



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code works (except the typo on the first include that I edited), just make sure you compile with `-std=c++11`

Comment: if you use `g++`, compile as `g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp`

Comment: what compiler are you using? if you use an IDE (like Eclipse or CodeBlocks), there is an option where you can specify the compiler flags, search online and you'll find.